# Removal of "dass": when?

Tags: word-usage

My understanding is that, sometimes, "dass" can be omitted and the word order changed accordingly:

> Ich weiß, dass er zu Hause ist.

or

> Ich weiß, er ist zu Hause.

Now the question: can the above transformation always be applied (ie, every time one would use "dass")? Or only in certain cases (if so, when)?

Comment: Ok, from that page and the linked wikipedia and canoo.net pages I can see that...it can "often" be done (I'm purposely ignoring the Indikativ -> Konjunktiv I change in indirect speech).

Comment: @I commend you for ignoring that. Nobody ever talks that way and by talking I mean also emails and so on

Comment: So you mean that normally the "dass" form is preferred? Or are you referring to the use of indicative rather than Subjunktiv for indirect speech?

Comment: @karoshi... indicative vs. subjunctive... for verbs like "sagen, glauben,..." plus a short follow up information, the dassless version is more common, I'd say for the dass-version is just boring. "Er sagt, er kommt." vs. "Er sagt, dass er kommt"... just one word more. The rest is the same